# How to generate ipa using visual studio for ios

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, ipa

I am developing an app for iOS using visual studio (phone gap). Can any one please assist me how to generate IPA for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is using official phonegap build site :
just upload your project and it will build files for you. totally easy.

https://build.phonegap.com

Be noticed that you need Apple developer account : 99$/year